# Can't archive app with Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode6, archive

I have packed my utility methods written in Swift into a `Cocoa Touch Framework`, and embedded into my app as this tutorial says: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg

It works well, but when I want to Submit to App Store, or create an Ad hoc Archive, it raise a lot of declaration error.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: ... so your app builds in debug mode but not release mode?  Sounds like a minor build settings issue.

Comment: you are right, I changed in both place framework and recipient app the `Build Active Architecture Only` to Yes / Yes, and now it works, I could archive it and install onto the device

Comment: No, that's not the solution.

Comment: why? it works now  for me ..

Comment: Because you will most likely want to provide multi cpu support for different devices. If that fix works then it looks like your framework doesn't provide all the required cpu architectures.

Comment: set to No / No it has the same result, able to archive, some linking error might be

Answer (score 0):

found solution here: https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c

just set `Build Active Architecture Only` to No / No.

[image]